# Compute time difference between two timestamps based on conditions in Impala

Tags: sql, impala

I'm using Impala and I have a table formatted like this:

```
ID        OLD_TIMESTAMP        NEW_TIMESTAMP
1234      2020-07-01 13:30     2020-07-01 18:00
2364      2020-07-02 07:30     2020-07-02 11:30
5746      2020-07-01 10:00     2020-07-03 12:30
5864      2020-07-10 23:45     2020-07-11 09:00
```

What I need to do is to compute, per each day and each ID, the difference (in hours) between NEW_TIMESTAMP and OLD_TIMESTAMP, but considering only the times between 08:00 and 23:30.
In other words, this should be the output:

```
ID        DAY            HOURS_DIFF
1234      2020-07-01     4.5
2364      2020-07-02     3.5
5746      2020-07-01     13.5
5746      2020-07-02     15.5
5746      2020-07-03     4.5
5864      2020-07-11     1.0
```

Is there any way to do this via a SQL query in Impala?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Impala, but I assume if you subtract two dates there, you'll get a number of **days** between them. This code is untested and probably not working for you now.

If your `new_timestamp`'s time is less than `23:30`, you should take `new_timestamp` unchanged, else you should take `new_timestamp`'s day and add to it `23:30`. At the end you'll get a timestamp, not greater than `23:30`

The similar procedure is with `old_timestamp` but you'll get a date, not less than `8:00`

Subtract two results and you'll get a number of days between the two, multiply it by 24 and it's a number of hours.

```
SELECT id, 
  trunc(old_timestamp, 'DD') AS day, 
  (CASE
    WHEN new_timestamp - trunc(new_timestamp, 'DD') > 24/23 + (24*60)/30 /*23 hours 30 minutes*/
    THEN minutes_add(trunc(new_timestamp, 'DD'), 23*60 + 30)
    ELSE new_timestamp
  END + CASE 
    WHEN old_timestamp - trunc(old_timestamp, 'DD') > 24/8 /*8 hours*/
    THEN old_timestamp
    ELSE minutes_add(trunc(old_timestamp, 'DD'), 8*60)
  END) * 24 AS hours_diff
FROM t;
```